# Ruby: How do I return a boolean value if the correct error is raised?

Tags: ruby, testing

I'm interested in comparing if the correct errors are raised for my code.
If the correct error is raised then it returns true, otherwise false.

Is there a way to go about it? Or would I need to write exception handling?

For example,

```
some_method(arg) == TypeError # => true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When an exception has been raised but not yet handled (in rescue, ensure, at_exit and END blocks) the global [variable $! will contain the current exception](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Exception.html) and $@ contains the current exception’s backtrace.

Do as below (*using inline `rescue` way*):

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > [1, 2, 3].first("two")
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):1:in 'first'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in '<main>'
2.0.0-p0 :002 > [1, 2, 3].first("two") rescue $!.class == TypeError
 => true 
2.0.0-p0 :003 > [1, 2, 3]['a'] rescue $!.class == TypeError
 => true 
2.0.0-p0 :004 > [1, 2, 3]['a']
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):4:in '[]'
    from (irb):4
    from /home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in '<main>'
2.0.0-p0 :005 > 1/0 rescue $!.class == TypeError
 => false 
2.0.0-p0 :006 >
```

[`TypeError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/TypeError.html)

> Raised when encountering an object that is not of the expected type.

```
[1, 2, 3].first("two")
```

> raises the exception:
>   *TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer*

In your case you could write as below :

```
some_method(arg) rescue $!.class == TypeError
```

Comment: This looks great, but it doesn't seem like the keywords puts, print, or p will print out the boolean if it is inline?

Comment: @Lambin I tried it in `irb` so I didn't use `p`, `puts`. But you can do `p some_method(arg) rescue $!.class == TypeError`.

Comment: To clarify, it will only puts in this form: `some_method(arg) rescue puts $!.class == TypeError`

Comment: @Lambin Huum.. I knew it.. I was doing this in IRB, so I didn't use puts. But you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Error handling seems straight forward enough:

```
begin
  some_method(arg)
  false
rescue TypeError
  true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it with rspec, you can do:

```
expect { some_method(arg) }.to raise_error(TypeError)
```

or

```
-> { some_method(arg) }.should raise_error(TypeError)
```